# Express routes based Json data from Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, express, npm, headless

I'm developing a blog with Express, the request-promise module and pug, consuming from a wordpress API. I would like to get the routes based on the Posts from wordpress.

the blog home, is working and rendering all the data and posts with the router index.js as this:

```
router.get('/blog', function(req, res, next) {
rp({uri: 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed', json: 
true})
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
res.render('blog', {
    posts: response, 
    title: 'Blog',
  });

  })
 .catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
});
```

So to get the routes and specific calls to the posts endpoints, i would like to make a loop of something like this:

```
  router.get('/blog/' + post.slug , function(req, res, next) {
rp({uri: 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + post.slug + '&_embed', json: true})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  res.render('blog/single', {
      posts: response, 
      title: 'Blog:' + post.title.rendered,

    });

})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
});
```

What would be the best approach to it?

**SOLVED:**

Instead of generating all the possible routes based on the Json response, the app evaluates if the url slug (a method that is part of expess) return a Json response with objects in it. If it does, will render the article with that slug, if the response from wordpress contains  0 elements, will show a 404. As the link's urls are generated from the blog's home, based on a previous json response with the articles slugs, we already know that all the links exist.

```
router.get('/blog/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
var slug = req.params.slug;

rp({uri: 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + slug + '&_embed', json: true})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  if(response.length === 0){
     res.render('404', {title: '404 Not found'}); 
  } else {
      res.render('blog/single', {
      posts: response, 
      title: 'Blog | ' + response[0].acf.meta_title,
      metaDesc: response[0].acf.meta_description
    });  
  }   
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
});
```

Comment: Whats your goal here Do you want to render single blog post at a time ?

Comment: The overall outcome would be to render the single posts, but this part is just to create the routes based on the json's slugs for each individual post. The "single" view that I've created, is for the individual rendering purpose.